# Interpret Naive Bayes output Python

Tags: python, naive-bayes-classifier

I am running Python code off Kaggle on the adult dataset using Naive Bayes. How do you interpret the results below, I know that it's for each instance the likelihood they make less than 50K or more than 50k.

How do you interpret say the first row in simple terms?  Is there  a way I could make it in standard form?

```
y_pred_prob_df = pd.DataFrame(data=y_pred_prob, columns=['Prob of - <=50K', 'Prob of - >50K'])

y_pred_prob_df
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with 'standard form'? The first row simply means that for the first observation the model predicts a probabiliy of 99.99% (basically 100%) that they make less than 50k.

Comment: Thanks. So row 2 [1],  predicts a probably of  99% that they make less than 50k AND 31% that will make more than 50k? @Oxbowerce

Comment: It indeed predicts a probability of 99.97% to make less than 50k, but the probability of making more than 50k is not 31% but 0.0312% (notice the e-4). The two numbers always add up to 100%.

Comment: @Oxbowerce  Thank you! that makes way more sense now . Much appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first row simply means that for the first observation the model predicts a probabiliy of 99.99% (basically 100%) that they make less than 50k. For the second records your model predicts a probability of 99.97% to make less than 50k, but the probability of making more than 50k is not 31% but 0.0312% (notice the e-4). The two numbers always add up to 100%.